# Determining the ramp-up speed for a stepper motor with its drive system

Tags: stepper-motor

How can the required ramp-up speed for a stepper motor which is attached to its drive system be determined?

Given that a stepper motor requires ramping-up to full velocity, and that ramp speed must be slow enough so that the motor doesn't simply vibrate in place, is there a known method for determining the ramp-up speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the stepper motor ramp up as quickly as possible, but no too quickly so that it stalls requires knowing when the motor shaft has actually turned to the next step.  There is, of course, some amount of lag time between when power is applied and when the shaft actually starts turning.  Perhaps you can get some idea of where your motor is by temporarily attaching a potentiometer to the system.  Note, depending on the package, you may have to break off the little tab to enable it to rotate completely.  There will be a "blank" spot in its rotation but it will still give you at least some idea of where you are at.[image]

Apply a voltage across the pot and watch it on a scope relative to the stepper control signals.  If you are ramp is too slow you can see when the stepper starts turning backwards for a bit until it settles in its next step position.  Adjust you ramp speed to make the next step so that the motor does not move backwards at all.

Also note that attaching a pot to your system changes the system by adding at least a tiny amount mechanical load to the stepper motor.  Hopefully this will not be too great and you can still get fairly close to optimum timing on the ramp up and ramp down.

Comment: Interesting idea.... but maybe a magnet and reed switch would work better and be less prone to wear.

Comment: @BG100 - I hadn't though about wearing out the pot.  I thought of this as a temporary test fixture and hoped you would be able to characterize the acceleration/deceleration timing before the pot wore out but maybe you're right.

Comment: Is this a situation for motor shaft encoders? I thought those were for turning steppers into servos. Hum... so the solution is to use an encoder. Sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

If you visit the web sites of companies that manufacturer quality stepper motors, you'll likely find documentation giving the theoretical way to calculate this.  You'll need to know a lot about the mechanical load, and be prepared to do a fair amount of math.  But if you are designing a printer to sell at a loss and make it up on ink... it's worth optimizing these things so you can use the cheapest motor that can meet your ramp speed requirements.

But in the more likely case, if you are building a one-off robot or hobby CNC machine or whatever, chances are you are going to buy the biggest motors you can get a good deal on (or you've already extracted them from that ancient printer), and then crank up the ramp-rate until you find it unreliable, then back off whatever safety factor you desire.

A well engineered and adjusted high voltage chopping drive amplifier will be necessary to get the maximum performance out of the motor without damaging its magnets.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing a design that is intented to be repeatable; so I'll have to do that math you spoke of. Would the Gecko drive be an example of a well engineered and adjusted high voltage chopping driver amplifier?

Comment: Repeatable implies reliable, but not necessarily optimized for needed performance at minimum price - so overbuying on motors might be possible.  Alternatively, if you don't have a hard performance requirement, you can just run it at whatever ramp/speed is reliable.  The Gecko modules I had years ago seemed a big improvement on what they replaced, but the surplus motors I had for that project were fairly high impedance, so performance wasn't going to be spectacular anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, stepper motors either run fine, or vibrate. The disconnect between working and too rapid acceleration is VERY obvious.

Assuming you have the whole thing set up, and you can freely run the axes back and forth, determining acceleration rates is therefore easy.

Basically, set the system up to cycle one of the axes back and forth, and then gradually increase the acceleration rate until it stops moving. Then back it off about 10-20%

Repeat for other axes.

Note: The system has to be loaded while testing.

Comment: This a good idea that can be done programatically; I'll keep that in mind.